# Make string from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, object

I've got this object

```
[{"name":"Fressnapf","isChecked":true},{"name":"Whiskas","isChecked":true},{"name":"Purina","isChecked":true}]
```

And i want to build a string like this:

> "Fressnapf","Whiskas","Purina"

But if the one of the isChecked boolean would be (false for example like this: `[{"name":"Fressnapf","isChecked":true},{"name":"Whiskas","isChecked":false},{"name":"Purina","isChecked":true}]` )

then the string should be look like this:

> "Fressnapf","Purina"

So i have a `$brands` object ( json form above) and now what?

Comment: `foreach` loop over the object, check if `isChecked` is true and create a string as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Decode json to PHP array  json_decode(<JSON>, true) the second parameter converts to array instead of object
$arrays = json_decode('[{"name":"Fressnapf","isChecked":true},{"name":"Whiskas","isChecked":true},{"name":"Purina","isChecked":true}]', true);

// Create an array to store the output data you want
$checked_names = [];

// Loop through the arrays of properties in your JSON to find out if the value isChecked is true and if so add the name to your checked_names array
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  if (!empty($array['isChecked'])) {
    $checked_names[] = $array['name'];    
  }
}

// Output with surrounding quotation marks.... implode will turn your array into a string with "glue" -- stuff in between the items... so you need the extra quotes on the outside as well
echo '"' . implode('", "', $checked_names) . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // --- Decode the json array.

    $array = json_decode('[{"name":"Fressnapf","isChecked":false},{"name":"Whiskas","isChecked":true},{"name":"Purina","isChecked":true}]');

    $string = array();

    // ---  Loop through the array. 
    foreach($array as $item){

        // --- Check to see if item is checked. If it is, stick it into array $string.
        if($item->isChecked != false){
            $string[] = $item->name;
        }
    }

    // --- Transform $string to an actual string.
    $string = implode(', ', $string);

    echo $string;
```

Comment: You can concatenation it to the front of the string, add this; '", "' for the implode() and concatenation it to the end.